# Twitch API json dictionary error list indices must be integers not str

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

```
try:
    response = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/followed', headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
except (KeyError, ValueError):
    print("Error - make sure your OAuth is formatted correctly in oauth.txt")
    sys.exit(1)
channelName = data["streams"]["channel"]["name"]
channelGame = data["streams"]["channel"]["game"]
channelViewers = str(data["streams"]["viewers"])
streamType = data["streams"]["stream_type"]
print(channelName, channelGame, channelViewers, streamType)
```

The error i get is list indices must be integers or slices, not str

From twitch i get a json dictionary:

> `{'streams': [{'_id': 2011610081, 'game': 'Sports & Fitness', 'broadcast_platform': 'live', 'community_id': '', 'community_ids': [], 'viewers': 12399, 'video_height': 900, 'average_fps':59, 'delay': 0, 'created_at': '2020-06-20T12:06:14Z', 'is_playlist': False, 'stream_type': 'live' }` the dictionary is a lot longer

How can i access on it without getting a error

Comment: ``streams`` is an list either u need to loop over or use index like ``data["streams"][0]``  to access the values.

Answer (score 0):

That is a list You Have itrate over it Something like This

Itrate Over it  using for loop

```
for i in data['streams']:
    print(i['_id'] ,i['game'])
```

or  select  index

```
data["streams"][0]['_id']
```